# specifying public address of apache ignite node with zookeeper discovery

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ignite

I have 3 apache ignite nodes in 3 different datacenters.

- datacenter-1
- datacenter-2
- datacenter-3

The nodes are visible  externally(and to each other) as `ignite-1-datacenter-1.myorg.com` ,`ignite-2-datacenter-2.myorg.com`,
and `ignite-3-datacenter-3.myorg.com`.

When I start a node, say `node-1` in `datacenter-1`, I want to inform zookeeper that the other 2 nodes should
connect to this node using the address `ignite-1-datacenter-1.myorg.com`.

How do I achieve that?

```
ZookeeperDiscoverySpi = new ZookeeperDiscoverySpi();
zk.setZKConnectionString("my-zookeeper-address");

IgniteConfiguratin cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setDiscovery(zk)

Ignite i = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/ignite-2.10/modules/zookeeper/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/zk/ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.java#L317) line gives us some intel about addresses that the `SPI` reports to Zookeeper. It seems like it should enough to specify a reachable host name [here](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setLocalHost-java.lang.String-). More information could be found in the [documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration#discovery). Rough example for the `ignite-1-datacenter-1.myorg.com` could look like:

```xml
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="localHost" value="ignite-1-datacenter-1.myorg.com"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for posting this answer. I tried this, but it did not work because with this config, Ignite was trying to bind to ignite-1-datacenter-1.myorg.com. But such an interface does not exist on the machine where Ignite is running.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet worked for me.

```html
ZookeeperDiscoverySpi = new ZookeeperDiscoverySpi();
zk.setZKConnectionString("my-zookeeper-address");

InetAddress local = InetAddres.getLocalHost();
Map<String, String> addresses = new HashMap<>();

String externalOrPublicNameForThisNode = "ignite-1-datacenter-1.myorg.com";
addresses.put(local.getHostAddress, externalOrPublicNameForThisNode );
AddressResolver resolver = new BasicAddressResolver(addresses);

TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
commSpi.setAddressResolver(resolver);

IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
igniteConfig.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);
igniteConfig.setAddressResolver(resolver);
igniteConfig.setDiscovery(zk);

Ignite i = Ignition.start(igniteConfig);
```